How to force shell interpolation in kubernetes environment variables
I'm using Helm and kubernetes to deploy a number of apps, i'm trying to inject a number of environmental variables using envFrom pointing to an already defined secret.
Some of the environmental variables there are referencing other environmental variables that are injected by kubernetes itself, like foo_SERVICE_PORT and foo_SERVICE_HOST variables, so the secret content is something like
  # Source: external-secret/templates/secret.yaml
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    name: backend-secret
  data:
-   foo_service_url: 'https://${foo_SERVICE_HOST}:${foo_SERVICE_PORT}'

I'm injecting these into the pods by using:
envFrom:
  - secretRef:
      name: backend-secret

The problem happens when i execute env from inside the pod the variable content is not interpolated, it contains the above string https://${foo_SERVICE_HOST}:${foo_SERVICE_PORT}
How can indicate to the pod that those should be interpolated?

Variable interpolation doesn't work when you're referencing variables from the secrets. It only works when you explicitly define variable in the YAML. Like this:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: pod
  name: pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: pod
    env:
    - name: foo_SERVICE_HOST
      value: test
    - name: foo_SERVICE_PORT
      value: "80"
    - name: foo_SERVICE_URL
      value: https://$(foo_SERVICE_HOST):$(foo_SERVICE_PORT)

In this case environment variable foo_SERVICE_URL will be set to https://test:80
